# create an infinitely extensible form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that needs to be able to multiply specific lines in the form, as well as then duplicate the entire form. In the concept example I am working on, there is a Name field, and a URL field. I need 1 name field, and up to 3 URL fields, but then I need to duplicate this entire grouping up to 3 times, and submit it via POST, but the number pairings can be different. 
As an example, the first group can have 1 name, 3 urls, the second have 1 url, and the third have 3 urls. I am able to multiply the number of URL fields, or the entire form, but if I have 2 URL fields, all multiples of the form have 2 URL fields, and I am then unable to change it in any of the forms.

Looking at the JSFiddle is much easier than just posting the code here, because you can see my code, as well as how it behaves. 
http://jsfiddle.net/wingdom/yCTpf/3/

Thank you for the help!

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
<div id="O1" class="clonedInput5">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="Ocount" id="Ocount" value="1" />
        <legend>Outbound App - Required</legend>
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="oname">
        </div>
        <div id="ourl1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput1">URL:
            <input type="text" name="ourl1" id="ourl1" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="ourlAdd" value="Add URL" />
            <input type="button" id="ourlDel" value="Remove URL" />
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="urlo" id="urlo" value="1" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="button" id="OAdd" value="Add Outbound" />
<input type="button" id="ODel" value="Rm Outbound" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#ourlAdd').click(function () {
var num = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
var newElem = $('#ourl' + num).clone().attr('id', 'ourl' + newNum);

// manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'ourl' + newNum).attr('name', 'ourl' + newNum);

// insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
$('#ourl' + num).after(newElem);

document.getElementById("urlo").value = newNum;


// enable the "remove" button
$('#ourlDel').attr('disabled', '');

// business rule: you can only add 5 names
if (newNum == 3) $('#ourlAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#ourlDel').click(function () {
var num = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
$('#ourl' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

document.getElementById("urlo").value = num - 1;

// enable the "add" button
$('#ourlAdd').attr('disabled', '');

// if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
if (num - 1 == 1) $('#ourlDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#ourlDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#OAdd').click(function () {
var num = $('.clonedInput5').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
var newElem = $('#O' + num).clone().attr('id', 'O' + newNum);



// insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
$('#O' + num).after(newElem);

document.getElementById("Ocount").value = newNum;


// enable the "remove" button
$('#ODel').attr('disabled', '');

// business rule: you can only add 5 names
if (newNum == 3) $('#OAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#ODel').click(function () {
var num = $('.clonedInput5').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
$('#O' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

document.getElementById("Ocount").value = num - 1;

// enable the "add" button
$('#OAdd').attr('disabled', '');

// if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
if (num - 1 == 1) $('#ODel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#ODel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: step 1: get rid of all id's so that duplication is easier.

Comment: That feels like a side step, I am just mirroring the names and IDs. It will only remove the second half of 2 lines in the javascript.

Comment: Right, but if you remove the id's and use *common* (not enumerated) classes to select your elements, you can do most of the events using delegation, thus avoiding having to re-bind events to new elements as new elements are created.

Comment: As far as your actual problem goes, you need to create a base form that never gets modified that you can copy to create your additional forms. I would do it as plan text rather than .clone, but that's up to you.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but can you point me to an example so I can get my head around it?

Comment: @KevinB Duplicate IDs are invalid and should be removed anyway

Comment: @Izkata right, but he's doing at least some work to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to store a copy of the original form initially, then use that copy to create your additional forms.

```
var $originalForm = $("#originalForm").clone();
```

Now, any time you need to create a new form, you just do: `$originalForm.clone()` then iterate through the elements within the form fixing ID's (assuming you don't go away from using id's.)

Though, personally i would do this a completely different way.

```
var formTemplate = "form template here, or get it from a <script type=\"text/template\"></text>";

function ExtendableForm() {
    this.$form = $(formTemplate).appendTo("body");
    this.bindEvents();
    return this.$form;
}
$.extend( ExtendableForm.prototype, {
    addAnotherURL: function(){
        this.$form.find(".wrap-url").append($(formTemplate).find(".wrap-url").children());
    },
    addAnotherName: function(){
        this.$form.find(".wrap-name").append($(formTemplate).find(".wrap-url").children());
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        this.$form
            .on("click", ".add-url", $.proxy(addAnotherURL,this))
            .on("click", ".add-name", $.proxy(addAnotherName,this));
    }
});



$("#addAnotherForm").click(function(){
    $("#form-container").append(new ExtendableForm());
}).click();
```

It could probably be made a bit dryer, but that's the basic idea. No one form is aware of or needs to care about any other form.

Comment: I think with where I am now, this would be a quicker solution. I just prototyped a solution with common classes, and that looks like I would have to rewrite a lot of what I have.

Comment: I was investigating the possibility of using your second suggestion, but how does the form template work?

Comment: It would just be a string that is the html for the form